# Forms get separated when Top Form is unminimized on top of another window

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms, a top form (form1) and a bottom form (form2) I created a semi transparent effect by setting the opacity of form2 to 0.7 and aligning form1 and form2. 
Here is the effect:
[image: Semi Transparent effect]

However, when no windows are active (other than form1) and I unminimize and application (e.g Mail) form2 gets blocked by the unminimized window (Mail, in this case)

Here is the problem:

[image: Problem]

I have tried minimizing and unminimizing form1 and form2 when form1 is unactive, but then that makes the window flash repeatedly when it is not the active window.

Here is my code:

```
        Form2 f2;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BackColor = Color.Red;
            this.TransparencyKey = Color.Red;
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            this.Location = new Point(200, 200);
            f2 = new Form2();
            f2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            f2.Location = new Point(200, 200);
            f2.Show();
        }

        private void AlignForms()
        {
            //align the forms by setting form2's location to this form 
            location and also the size
            f2.Location = this.Location;
            f2.Size = this.Size;
            f2.WindowState = this.WindowState;

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //set update var from class 1 to false
            update = false;

            //make the background color same as transparency key
            this.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
            this.TransparencyKey = Color.LightSlateGray;

            //make the navpanel  transparent
            navpanel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

            //call the align forms method to align the back and front forms
            AlignForms();

            //start the timer to align the forms every 1 ms
            timer1.Start();
        }

         private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //align the forms
            AlignForms();

        }
```

Can you please help me

Comment: Color.Red trips an Aero bug.  Which is sometimes useful to create a transparent window that can still detect the mouse.  But not what you want, use Color.Fuchsia or Color.Lime instead.